# Include Copyright comment in header on existing and new class via eclipse formatter

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, formatting

I want include copyright comment on the top of every java file. I want to do it via eclipse formatter.

If it is not possible, please suggest any other way to include the copyright in existing java file.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try Eclipse Releng Tools [here](https://wiki.eclipse.org/WTP/Releng/Tools)

2. Write a script to update each file and add first line - use eclipse find and replace regex
   http://java.dzone.com/articles/using-regular-expressions

Answer (score 0):

Although it may not perfectly suit the intended *approach* (that is, using an eclipse plugin for that) : Once I created a small utility class that does exactly this.

It collects a list of all `.java` files in a given source directory. For each of the resulting files, it looks for the first line starting with the word `"package"`. If the part *above* this line is **not** empty, then it will assume that a header is already present, and skip this file. Otherwise, it will insert a header (which is contained in some template file) *before* the line starting with `"package"`.

This could arbitrarily be improved and generalized, but I only once wrote it down in order to quickly insert copyright headers into the files of an existing code base, and it worked well. Maybe you (or others) find it helpful.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class HeaderInserter
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String headerTemplateFileName = "HeaderTemplate.txt";
        String path = "C:/Workspace/HeaderInserter/src";
        insertHeaders(path, headerTemplateFileName);
    }

    private static void insertHeaders(String path, String headerTemplateFileName)
    {
        FilenameFilter filenameFilter = new FilenameFilter()
        {
            @Override
            public boolean accept(File dir, String name)
            {
                return name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".java");
            }
        };
        List<String> headerLines = readLines(headerTemplateFileName); 
        List<File> files = listFiles(new File(path), filenameFilter);
        for (File file : files)
        {
            System.out.println("Inserting header into "+file);
            handle(file, headerLines);
        }
        System.out.println("Done");
    }

    private static void handle(File inputFile, List<String> headerLines)
    {
        List<String> lines = readLines(inputFile.getPath());

        int index = lineIndexStartingWith(lines, "package");
        if (index == -1)
        {
            System.err.println("No 'package' line found in "+inputFile);
            return;
        }
        if (index > 0)
        {
            List<String> removedLines = lines.subList(0, index);
            String removedPart = createString(removedLines);
            String removedContents = removedPart.replaceAll("\n", "");
            if (removedContents.trim().length() > 0)
            {
                System.err.println("Non-empty header found in "+inputFile);
                System.err.println(removedPart);
                System.err.println("Skipping");
                return;
            }
        }
        List<String> keptLines = lines.subList(index, lines.size());
        List<String> writtenLines = new ArrayList<String>();
        writtenLines.addAll(headerLines);
        writtenLines.addAll(keptLines);
        String writtenContent = createString(writtenLines);

        File outputFile = new File(inputFile.getName()+"_header");
        boolean written = writeContent(outputFile, writtenContent);
        if (written)
        {
            boolean deleted = inputFile.delete();
            if (!deleted)
            {
                System.err.println(
                    "Could not delete old input file: "+inputFile);
                return;
            }

            boolean renamed = outputFile.renameTo(inputFile);
            if (!renamed)
            {
                System.err.println("Could not rename "+outputFile);
                System.err.println("              to "+inputFile);
                return;
            }
            System.out.println("Inserted  header into "+inputFile);
        }
    }

    private static int lineIndexStartingWith(
        List<String> lines, String prefix)
    {
        for (int i=0; i<lines.size(); i++)
        {
            String line = lines.get(i);
            if (line.trim().startsWith(prefix))
            {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    private static String createString(List<String> lines)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (String line : lines)
        {
            sb.append(line).append("\n");
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    private static boolean writeContent(
        File outputFile, String writtenContent)
    {
        try (FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(outputFile))
        {
            fw.write(writtenContent);
            fw.close();
            return true;
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }

    private static List<String> readLines(String fileName) 
    {
        try
        {
            return Files.readAllLines(
                Paths.get(fileName), Charset.defaultCharset());
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    private static List<File> listFiles(
        File rootDirectory, FilenameFilter filenameFilter)
    {
        List<File> result = new ArrayList<File>();
        listFiles(rootDirectory, filenameFilter, result);
        return result;
    }

    private static void listFiles(
        File file, FilenameFilter filenameFilter, List<File> result)
    {
        if (!file.isDirectory())
        {
            if (filenameFilter.accept(file.getParentFile(), file.getName()))
            {
                result.add(file);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            File files[] = file.listFiles();
            for (File f : files)
            {
                listFiles(f, filenameFilter, result);
            }
        }
    }
}
```